# How to prevent some files from showing up on the Ibuffer list?

Tags: ibuffer

On my IBuffer I keep seeing `*lsp-log*` and `*pyls::stderr*` files.

```
[ Default ]
 *% *lsp-log*                516 Fundamental
 *% *pyls::stderr*           264 Special          (pyls stderr open)
```

---

Is it possible to prevent these file to be hidden in the `Ibuffer` or basically hide or remove  them.

My approach does not make any change:

```
(recentf-mode 1)
(setq recentf-max-saved-items 50)
(setq recentf-max-menu-items 50)
(setq recentf-exclude '("*lsp-log*"
                        "pyls::stderr"
                        ))
```

More general question should be as: how can I prevent some files show up on the `Ibuffer list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to prevent these file to be hidden in the `Ibuffer` or basically hide or remove them.

Yes, have a look at the user option `ibuffer-never-show-predicates`:

```
ibuffer-never-show-predicates is a variable defined in ‘ibuf-ext.el’.

Its value is nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
  You can customize this variable.

A list of predicates (a regexp or function) for buffers not to display.
If a regexp, then it will be matched against the buffer’s name.
If a function, it will be called with the buffer as an argument, and
should return non-nil if this buffer should not be shown.
```

So, you could either [customise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) this user option to include the buffer names `*lsp-log*` and `*pyls::stderr*` (using [regexp syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html)), or you could write something like the following yourself:

```el
(setq ibuffer-never-show-predicates
      (mapcar #'regexp-quote '("*lsp-log*" "*pyls::stderr*")))
```

> My approach does not make any change:

That's to be expected, as `recentf` and `ibuffer` are different packages that don't share any common functionality.